# TypeScript 3.5.1 Generic breaking change

Tags: typescript

TypeScript 3.5.1 introduced a breaking change wherein unconstrained generic argument types are treated as "unknown" rather than {}. It appears to me that, in some cases, even constrained generic argument types are being treated as unknown.

The code below compiles fine using TypeScript 3.4.5.

```
interface IConfig {
    [key: string]: string;
}

export class ConfigHandlers<T extends IConfig> {
    handleString(name: string, value: string, options: T) {
        options[name] = value;
    }

    handleNumber(name: string, value: number, options: T) {
        options[name] = value.toString();
    }
}
```

Since, in the above example, T is constrained to be like an IConfig, it should be possible to make the specified assignment to options[name] (name is a string and keys of type string are explicitly allowed). However, the above code in TypeScript 3.5.1 results in an error "Type 'string' cannot be used to index type 'T'.

The workaround (at least in this case) is to change the type of the options argument to be IConfig. I'm not sure if this tracks to all instances of similar code.

Is this an invalid new behavior or is the original code actually wrong for some reason?

Comment: This is [intended behavior](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31661) due to a [different change](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769) which is documented [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#fixes-to-unsound-writes-to-indexed-access-types).